# Validating a model and introducing a new predictor in glm

Tags: r, prediction, glm

I am hitting my head against the computer...
I have a prediction model in R that goes like this

```
m.final.glm <- glm(binary_outcome ~ rcs(PredictorA, parms=kn.a)  + rcs(PredictorB, parms=kn.b) +  PredictorC , family = "binomial", data = train_data)
```

I want to validate this model on test_data2 - first by updating the linear predictor (lp)

```
train_data$lp <- predict(m.final.glm, train_data)
test_data2$lp <- predict(m.final.glm, test_data2)

lp2 <- predict(m.final.glm, test_data2)
m.update2.lp <- glm(binary_outcome ~ 1, family="binomial", offset=lp2, data=test_data2)
m.update2.lp$coefficients[1]

m.final.update2.lp <- m.final.glm
m.final.update2.lp$coefficients[1] <- m.final.update2.lp$coefficients[1] + m.update2.lp$coefficients[1]
m.final.update2.lp$coefficients[1]
p2.update.lp <- predict(m.final.update2.lp, test_data2, type="response")
```

This gets me to the point where I have updated the linear predictor, i.e. in the summary of the model only the intercept is different, but the coefficients of each predictor are the same.

Next, I want to include a new predictor (it is categorical, if that matters), PredictorD, into the updated model. This means that the model has to have the updated linear predictor and the same coefficients for Predictors A, B and C but the model also has to contain Predictor D and estimate its significance.

How do I do this? I will be very grateful if you could help me with this. Thanks!!!

Comment: Add a new variable __while keeping the coefficients of all the other variables unchanged__?

Comment: Well, yes. I am doing an external validation of a model, and I need to test an additional variable together with all other variables of the model. I was told I had to keep everything unchanged and to "just add" this new predictor. The new predictor is not included in the original model. Sounds like a good plan? I feel totally lost...

Comment: I think what you were told to do is to add the new variable and keep all the other variables unchanged (not the coefficients). If this is the case, then you can do this easily with the `update()` function, and then compare the two models with an ANOVA. Keeping the coefficients unchanged is probably not possible, since it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: But what you are suggesting is to create a whole new model and to compare this with the original model - this is different from my task since I am doing this on a validation dataset. I want to see whether adding the new predictor will lead to better performance of the original model.

Comment: That is how you do it, your approach is wrong.

Comment: But your suggestion is also wrong (sorry to say). I am trying to do a model revision, not to compare two models. Hope you see the difference.